# Signing an APK results in AssertionError at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.getPath(BuildToolInfo.java:244)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signing

I am trying to generate a signed APK with Android Studio and I got this error.

I'm sure that my passwords and such are correct because i've tried the same process with arbitrary strings and they fail with the expected errors (password wrong)

Google has not proven useful for this error, does anyone have any clue what's going on?

I am using 0.8.6

[image]

[image: assertion error]

```
    null
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.getPath(BuildToolInfo.java:244)
        at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.createAndAlignApk(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:380)
        at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.access$200(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:81)
        at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$1$1.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:157)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Comment: update your AS to 0.8.12 and try again...

Comment: I'm using windows, and 0.8.6 was the first thing offered on the android website.

Comment: They released 0.8.12 today, so worth a try to update :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Short introduction)
Hey, I had the same problem with IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5, exactly the same stacktrace. I remembered, it worked with 13.1.4 but this wasn't on my machine. So I tried 13.1.1. This version, though, told me it didn't find the `zipalign` tool. This pointed me to the right direction.

**Solution**

I updated "everything" in my Android SDK Manager (via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager). So, currently I have

```
Android SDK Tools Rev. 23.0.4
Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 20
Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 20
Android API 16, 19 and 20
Android Support Library Rev. 20
Android Play Billing Library Rev. 5
Android USB Driver Rev. 11
```

I guess one Android API is enough, though.
Now I'm able to build a signed APK again.

Comment: In my case, updating JUST the build-tools to Rev 20 fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case installing build tools rev. 20 AND stopping and restarting IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 fixed the problem.

Comment: Make sure to delete any OLD Android SDK Build-Tools from inside the SDK manager. I had version 18. After deletion it doesn't even show up in the list...

Answer (score 2):

That call stack is consistent with it trying to find the **zipalign** tool, which moved in SDK 23. I'm guessing you're using an Android Studio released after SDK 23 (which is the case if you're running 0.8.6) and trying to use an old SDK. If that's the case update your SDK and you should be fine.

There's a bug report that documents the behavior here, but note that the bug was closed as WorkingAsIntended -- it's up to tooling to change, and if users have any scripts or other behavior that rely on **zipalign** being in a specific place, that needs to change as well.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72611

Answer (score 0):

Manually updating Android SDK Build-tools to the latest version fixed it for me. You can't just update all - I had to manually deselect the old package and install the newest package.